# How to send node command line arguments in jest test

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have a utility.js which uses program arguments through `process.argv`.

When I run `jest -t 'utility-spec' --arg1 value1 --arg2 value2` it's throwing exception. Failed to run the test.

> (node:8956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): ● Unrecognized CLI Parameters:
>
> Following options were not recognized:   ["arg1",
>   "arg2"]

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into the same question and found this answer:

> Jest doesn't accept node arguments unfortunately. I recommend testing your utility by making a programmatic interface. You can also overwrite process.argv in your test before requiring your module.

[Issue 5089](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5089)

Seems like it's not possible.

Comment: While links are helpful, they can get broken or changed over time so it's good practice to quote or summarize the relevant parts of the link in your answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19184019)

Comment: @daniu The link you provided is the same guy asked question here. I'm everywhere. :sunglass: